# WPF StaticResource could not be resolved

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I am trying to learn Prism with little knowledge of WPF. i'm following a sample application with the following structure:

[image]

In project ModuleA, there is a label with style with a StaticResource Header1:
[image]

There is no reference to the styling project from project ModuleA.
[image]

When I do the same in my project, I get the following error:

> The resource 'Header1' could not be resolved.

[image]

I think that I have the same code for everything. Anyone knows what I have to do?

Comment: Can you show us the content of the `App.xaml` file in that project? Asking because MahApps requires several ResourceDictionaries to be defined there. Just a guess, though.

Answer (score 0):

### Include `PrismMahApps.Sample.Infrastructure`

`Header1` is defined in that project, in a file called `Label.xaml`.
It's unclear to me what you mean when you say

> There is no reference to the styling project from project ModuleA.

My first guess is that you overlooked `PrismMahApps.Sample.Infrastructure`, believing it to contain no required styling elements.